# I am getting an error in rendering some of the things from cricket api

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, backend

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const https = require("https");
const app = express();
app.get("/", function (request, response) {
  //it is the endpoint of the api
  const url =
    "https://api.cricapi.com/v1/currentMatches?apikey=acdcba6a-5e79-4d7d-8efc-650c785096e2&offset=0";
  https.get(url, function (res) {
    console.log(res);
    console.log(res.statusCode);
    response.write("<h1><center>Cricket Score</center></h1><hr>");
    response.write;
    res.on("data", function (data) {
      const cricket = JSON.parse(data);
      for (var i = 0; i < cricket.data.length; i++) {
        //it is stringify the r component of data.score[0].r
        const cricketscore0 = JSON.stringify(cricket.data[i].score[0].r);
        const cricketscore1 = JSON.stringify(cricket.data[i].score[1].r);
        const cricketwickets0 = JSON.stringify(cricket.data[i].score[0].w);
        const cricketwickets1 = JSON.stringify(cricket.data[i].score[1].w);
        const cricketover0 = JSON.stringify(cricket.data[i].score[0].o);
        const cricketover1 = JSON.stringify(cricket.data[i].score[1].o);
        response.write("<h2>\n" + cricket.data[i].name + "</h2>");
        response.write("<h3>\nMatch type :- " + cricket.data[0].matchType);
        response.write(
          "<h3>\n" +
            cricket.data[i].score[0].inning +
            " :-" +
            cricketscore0 +
            "/" +
            cricketwickets0 +
            "(" +
            cricketover0 +
            ")</h3>"
        );
        response.write(
          "<h3>\n" +
            cricket.data[i].score[1].inning +
            " :-" +
            cricketscore1 +
            "/" +
            cricketwickets1 +
            "(" +
            cricketover1 +
            ")</h3>"
        );
        response.write("<h3><em>" + cricket.data[i].status + "</em></h3>");
      }
      response.send();
      console.log();
    });
  });
});
app.listen(3000, function (req, res) {
  console.log("The server is running on the port 3000");
});
```

I am getting into rendering the components of the `data.score[1]`. It is giving an error that they are undefined so I want you to please help me out in the above problem. I am unable to render it using for loop but I can get it if specify the value of I individually. when I am using for loop it is saying that components of `data.score[1]` does not exit. please help me out in this case. Please specify the answer and if possible please tell the problem with a solution code so that I can understand my problem and know what I am doing and avoid it in the future

This question will resolve the problems related to the rendering of things through APIs also. Please help me out with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have made use of axios for this. You may use https. some of the objects are undefined for score index 1 that is why you are getting that error.

```
    I have made use of axios for this. You may use https. some of the objects are undefined for score index 1 that is why you are getting that error.

    const express = require('express');
const axios = require("axios");

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded())


const url = "https://api.cricapi.com/v1/currentMatches?apikey=acdcba6a-5e79-4d7d-8efc-650c785096e2&offset=0";


// middleware
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  next()
});

const getCricketScors = async () => {
  const resData = await axios.get(url)
  // console.log(resData.data)
  const { data } = resData
  // console.log(data)
  return data
}

app.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await getCricketScors()
    // res.status(200).json(data)


    if (!data) {
      res.write("<h1><center>Cricket Score</center></h1><hr>");
      res.write("<h4><center>Somthing went wrong</center></h4>");
      res.send();
      return
    }

    res.write("<h1><center>Cricket Score</center></h1><hr>");
    res.write;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      const score0 = JSON.stringify(data[i].score[0])

      const cricketscore0 = score0.r;
      const cricketwickets0 = score0.w;
      const cricketover0 = score0.o;

      if (data[i].score.length > 1) {
        const score1 = JSON.stringify(data[i].score[1])

        const cricketscore1 = score1.r;
        const cricketwickets1 = score1.w;
        const cricketover1 = score1.o;
      } else {
        const cricketscore1 = '-'
        const cricketwickets1 = '-'
        const cricketover1 = '-'
      }
      res.write("<h2>\n" + data[i].name + "</h2>");
      res.write("<h3>\nMatch type :- " + data[0].matchType);

      res.write(
        "<h3>\n" +
        score0.inning +
        " :-" +
        cricketscore0 +
        "/" +
        cricketwickets0 +
        "(" +
        cricketover0 +
        ")</h3>"
      );

      if (score1) {
        res.write(
          "<h3>\n" +
          score1?.inning +
          " :-" +
          cricketscore1 +
          "/" +
          cricketwickets1 +
          "(" +
          cricketover1 +
          ")</h3>"
        );
      }


      res.write("<h3><em>" + data[i].status + "</em></h3>");

    }
    res.send();
    } catch (error) {
     console.log({ error })
     res.status(500).json(error.message)
   }
 });

  app.listen(port, '0.0.0.0', () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`);
  });
```

Comment: But how are they undefined when i am opening the api through postman or chrome they are showing

Comment: as i already said in my previous answer the data being returned from api have different length of objects in all array objects. if i taken an example of score property which is an array. For all objects being returned it has different length i.e. some has empty some has 1 and some hase 2 objects in array. So when you try to render that score with objects in your html it will giving error for the 2nd object as it is undefined.